# MongoDB: Update all documents with new field based on value of another field in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I find the documentation for [MongoDB java-driver](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/update/) insufficient for this question.

I want to update all documents in my collection with a new field based on the value of another field(a timestamp).

Should I just query a `FindIterable<Document>`, do a `.forEach` and perform my operations in the `apply` method? In that case, what would be the correct syntax for this?

This is what I have so far. `Document.put` does not do the trick.

```
private void addDayOfWeekField(MongoDatabase mdb, String collectionName){

    FindIterable<Document> iterable = mdb.getCollection(collectionName).find();
    iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
        @Override
        public void apply(Document document) {
            long timestamp = Long.parseLong(document.get("timestamp").toString())*1000l;
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
            document.put("day_of_week", cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
            document.put("hour_of_day", cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        }
    });
}
```

The code below updates all documents with a new field, but without a value. UpdateOne might be the right way to go as Philipp states.

```
mdb.getCollection(collectionName).updateMany(
            new Document(),
            new Document("$set", new Document("hour_of_day", ""))
    );
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`document.put` makes a change to the local copy of the document in the Java VM. The database does not notice this. To send that change back to the database, use [collection.updateOne](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#updateOne-org.bson.conversions.Bson-org.bson.conversions.Bson-com.mongodb.client.model.UpdateOptions-) or [collection.replaceOne](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#replaceOne-org.bson.conversions.Bson-TDocument-com.mongodb.client.model.UpdateOptions-).

Comment: I suppose collection.updateMany would be the correct one to use since I am updating every document. But, how would the syntax look like? The documentation is horrible...

Comment: @kongshem updateMany is used when you want to perform *the same* update on a number of documents. But when I understood you correctly, you want to make *different* updates to all documents.

Comment: That's true. But I believe I should use forEach to perform the operations because I have different updates to each document. I believe I have to do something with the "$set" parameter, but idk.